# Variation of Seshadri constants in families - Example 5.1.11, [PAG1] R.Lazarsfeld

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I find it difficult to demonstrate a certain proposition about how Seshadri’s constants vary "as a family". This is **Example 5.1.11** from Lazarfeld's book "*Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I*", page 272 :

> Let $X$ be an irreducible projective variety, $T$ an other variety, $L$ a divisor on $X$ and $p : X \to T$ a surjective proper morphism. Assume that we have a section $x : T \to X$ of $p$ such that $p$ is smooth along the image of $x$. Write $X_t := p^{-1}(t)$, $L_t = L \vert_ {X_t}$ and $x_t = x(t)$ for every $t \in T$. Then $\varepsilon(X_t, L_t ; x_t)$ is constant off the union of countably many proper subvarieties of $T$. If $t^*$ is a very general point, then $\varepsilon(X_t, L_t ; x_t) \leq \varepsilon(X_{t^*}, L_{t^*} ; x_{t^*})$ for every $t \in T$, i.e. Seshadri constants can only "jump down".

I tried to follow the indication of the book to demonstrate this, namely : "*Blow up along the image of $x$ and apply $1.4.14$.*" with

> **Proposition 1.4.14. (Nefness in families) :** Let $f : X \to T$ be a surjective proper morphism of varieties, and let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. With the same notations as above, if $L_0$ is nef for some given $0 \in T$, there there is a countable union $B \subset T$ of proper subvarieties of $T$, not containing $0$, such that $L_t$ is nef for all $t \in T \backslash B$.

**What I tried to do :** let $t_0 \in T$ be a fixed point. If $\mu : \tilde{X} \to X$ is the blow up of $X$ along $x(T)$ with exceptional divisor $E$, then we can consider the surjective proper morphism $\tilde{p} := p \circ \mu : \tilde{X} \to T$ with the line bundle $\mu^*L - \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) E$ on $\tilde{X}$. By definition of $\varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0})$, we know that
$$\big(\mu^*L - \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) E\big)_{t_0} = \mu^* L_{t_0} - \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) E_{x_{t_0}}$$
is nef on $\tilde{X}$. Applying $1.4.14$, we obtain a countable union $B(t_0) \subset T$ of proper subvarieties of $T$ not containg $t_0$ such that
$$\big(\mu^*L - \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) E\big)_{t} = \mu^* L_{t} - \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) E_{x_{t}}$$
is nef on $\tilde{X}$ for every $t \in T \backslash B(t_0)$. This implies, by definition of the Seshadri constant, that
$$\forall t \in T \backslash B(t_0) ~:~ \varepsilon(X_{t_0}, L_{t_0} ; x_{t_0}) \leq \varepsilon(X_{t}, L_{t} ; x_{t}) ~~(*)$$
**Finally, what I get is the following result :** for every $t_0 \in T$, there exists a countable union $B(t_0) \subset T$ of proper subvarieties not containg $t_0$ such that $(*)$ holds. This is different from Lazarsfeld’s assertion at the level of quantifiers which is :

> There exists a countable union $B \subset T$ of proper subvarieties of $T$ such that, for every $t$ in $T$ and for every $t^*$ in $T \backslash B$, we have $\varepsilon(X_{t}, L_{t} ; x_{t}) \leq \varepsilon(X_{t^*}, L_{t^*} ; x_{t^*})$.

I guess my mistake is to take $t_0$ at the beginning, but I don’t see how else to proceed. Do you have any indications?